# JqGrid multipage selection

Tags: c#, jqgrid

I am using the Trirand jqgrid version 5.0.0(Paid). I have grid in my form with paging. My requirement is to select all records from all pages when select all.

I have tried `multiselect: true` and `multiPageSelection: true` together, but it is not working. I have update panels on my form.

Any recommendations would be helpful

TIA.

Comment: What is your data - local or server side? Just to know - there is no option multiPageSelection - from where you get this option - this option is present in free jqgrid not in paid version?

Comment: @TonyTomov Thank you for the response. My data is coming from server. Is there any work out to select records from all pages when select all?

Comment: If the data comes from the server, we do not know the ids of the data and can not do a selection. We know only the ids of the current loaded page. Not sure, if there is a solution in this case, if I correctly understand the requirement.

Comment: Yeah. That is the requirement. Thank you for the response